# Copy vector to vector

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I'm trying to copy one vector to another using `std::copy``

```
vector<note_name> notes =  AppSettings::getAllNotes();
copy(notes.begin(), notes.end(), song.noteList);
```

The function `getAllNotes()` returns a `vector<note_name>` and noteList is a public member of the same type. When I try to run I'm getting:

[image]

So I think there's some problem with the fact that the vector uses the type `note_name`, but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need an output *iterator*, too. If `noteList` already has the required size, say:

```
copy(notes.begin(), notes.end(), song.noteList.begin());
```

If it is empty and you want to *insert* the copied range, `#include <iterator>` and say:

```
copy(notes.begin(), notes.end(), std::back_inserter(song.noteList));
```

However, as @Mike points out, it may be even simpler to say one of the following:

```
song.noteList = notes;                            // keep both
```

```
AppSettings::getAllNotes().swap(song.noteList);   // dispose of the temporary
```

Comment: Although the intent might be expressed more clearly by `song.noteList = notes;` (or `song.noteList.assign(notes.begin(),notes.end())` if the container types are different).

Answer (score 0):

2 methods I like from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ways-to-copy-a-vector-in-cplusplus) are:

1. Pass the vector in the constructor:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v1({ 7, 6, 4, 5 });
std::vector<int> v2(v1);
```

2. `assign()` function:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v1({ 7, 6, 4, 5 });
std::vector<int> v2;
v2.assign(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

Comment: Related: If you want to **insert** copy a vector into another vector (appending), use `insertInto.insert(insertInto.end(), insertMe.begin(), insertMe.end());`